# Условия выбора checkbox

Tags: checkbox

Имеется такая схема:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="est()" value="3000" id="glv" />
    <label for="cms">Главный чекбокс</label>
<div id="modules">
     <input type="checkbox" onchange="est()" value="1000" id="otz" />
           <label for="otz">1</label><br>
     <input type="checkbox" onchange="est()" value="1000" id="news" />
           <label for="news">2</label><br>
     <input type="checkbox" onchange="est()" value="1000" id="photo" />
           <label for="photo">3</label><br>
</div>
```

Как при выборе любого checkbox из группы #modules автоматически ставилась галочка с #glv.
В случае, если убирается галочка из любого пункта группы #modules, галочка с #glv все равно остается активной?

Comment: @3aka4ka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

[[@3aka4ka](/users/32062/3aka4ka)](/users/32062/3aka4ka), вы не уточнили: на чистом JS или с использованием какой-нибудь библиотеки, поэтому даю [вариант на чистом](http://jsfiddle.net/en8rLva3/):

```
var d = document,
    mainChbx = d.getElementById('glv'),
    chbxGroup = d.querySelectorAll('#modules input[type="checkbox"]'),
    cnt = chbxGroup.length;

[].forEach.call(d.querySelectorAll('#modules input[type="checkbox"]'), function(chbx){
    chbx.addEventListener('change', checkboxRevision, false);
});

mainChbx.addEventListener('change', function(){
    var that = this;
    [].forEach.call(chbxGroup, function(chbx){
        chbx.checked = that.checked;
    });
}, false);

function checkboxRevision(){
    mainChbx.checked = (d.querySelectorAll('#modules input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == cnt);
    return false;
}
```

И все onclick поубирайте из тегов.